# Input tag and table height

Tags: asp.net, button, html-table

I have asp.net Button, table and Button as below:

```
<table style="width: 600px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="float: right;">
                <asp:Button ID="_btn01" runat="server" Text="GO" />
                <table class="IHCommandButtonContainer" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="IHCommandButtonL"><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Test/Images/btn_Search.gif" /></td>
                        <td class="IHCommandButtonM"><span>Search</span></td>
                        <td class="IHCommandButtonR"><img src="/Test/Images/btn_R.gif" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that I cannot put them in the same line.
They look like as below:

[image]

My css is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .IHCommandButtonContainer   { height: 21px; border: 0px; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; }
    .IHCommandButtonL           { width: 22px; height: 21px; }
    .IHCommandButtonL   input   { width: 22px; height: 21px; }
    .IHCommandButtonM           { background-image: url(/Test/Images/btn_M.gif); height: 21px; font-size: 9pt; font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Dotum; }
    .IHCommandButtonM   span    { margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px; }
    .IHCommandButtonM_          { background-image: url(/Test/Images/btn_M_.gif); height: 21px; font-size: 9pt; font-family: Sans-serif, Arial, Dotum; }
    .IHCommandButtonM_  span    { margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px; }
    .IHCommandButtonR           { width: 3px; height: 21px; }
    .IHCommandButtonR   img     { width: 3px; height: 21px; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```

How can I put them in the same line?
Like 2 GO buttons are in the same line, but the table in the middle is upper than them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User "vertical-align" attribute in your css. Set the value to "middle".

Cheers

Comment: which css class do u mean to put vertical-align?

Comment: Use Developer Tools to see what happens when you set the "vertical-align" css attribute. By the way, in your situation I think you should set it on the container which is a table element. "vertical-align" has many values such as "middle", "top", "bottom" or "baseline", choose the relevant value you need. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Vertical align is the right answer, although I'm against to use the 'Developer Tools'...
The trick is to understand what you are doing...

this would help you: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

take notice that putting the buttons in "display: inline-block" will help you to fix this problem easy!

Comment: First of all, the fact that you are against to use the "Developer Tools" or anything else does not relates to the question. However it is your opinion and I respect that. Also about the "display" attribute you mentioned, Although setting this attribute might helps the view seems perfect (in this situation), it has not been made to do such a thing. Duty of "display" attribute is something and duty of "vertical-align" is something else. Cheers